# How can I redirect all domains to their root domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm using MODX to host multiple domains in a single directory. I need the subdomain 'www' to redirect to the root domain for each one. If I specify the domain in my rewrite rule in the typical fashion then all the domains redirect to the one I've specified:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I duplicate this code once for each domain I get redirect loops. How can I redirect each one to it's own root domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: you were too fast ++

Comment: @anubhava Although unfortunately still not as good as you ;-)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! This is a huge help. :)